# Json.Net throws OutOfMemoryException only in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, json.net, deserialization

I have some strange behavior which I can't figure out.

I'm using a WCF service to save files to a certain DB table. The WCF service has a single method which takes a JSON string as parameter. The JSON in this case is a serialized command which contains a `List<FileData>` amongst other properties. The WCF service deserializes the JSON and runs the `CommandHandler` for this specific command.

An end-user ran into a bug when he tried to upload a file with a size of 52 MB. The WCF service returned a 404 error.

I was able to reproduce this in Visual Studio. After changing the config file according to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2015/04/16/wcf-sending-large-file-to-wcf-fails-with-404-not-found-error/), the 404 disappeared.

But now a new exception appeared: While the command is successfully serialized client side, successfully processed by WCF, the deserialization throws an `OutOfMemoryException`. This is the top of the stacktrace:

> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadData(Boolean append, Int32 charsRequired)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadData(Boolean append)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringIntoBuffer(Char quote)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseString(Char quote)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAsBytesInternal()
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsBytes()
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)

I wrote a unittest to prove the bug. But against all odds this test passes, in other words, no `OutOfMemoryException` is thrown.

The test for the sake of completeness:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void LoadBigFile_SerializeDeserialize_DoesntThrowOutOfMemoryException()
    {
        // Arrange
        byte[] bytes = new byte[80000000];
        Random r = new Random(23);
        r.NextBytes(bytes);

        var command = new SomeCommand(new List<FileData>
        {
            new FileData(
                fileFullName: @"D:\SomePdfFile.pdf",
                modifyDate: DateTime.MaxValue,
                data: bytes
                )
        });

        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(command);

        // Act
        var deserializedCommand = 
              JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeCommand>(data);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(bytes.Length, deserializedCommand.Files.First().Data.Length);
    }
```

So, I took my chances and changed the config file in production and tried to upload the same file. And that just works!!! No `OutOfMemoryException`!

Now my question is, why does the `OutOfMemoryException` only happen in Visual Studio, while a unittest in the same instance of VS doesn't? It feels a bit strange that I can't test uploading big files in Visual Studio, while it works in production. Notice that I also tried to run in Debug as in Release Mode.

Some details:

- Using Json.Net 7.0.1
- Visual Studio 2015, update 2
- WCF hosted in IIS Express locally, IIS in production
- Windows 10 latest build 64 bit
- Production server Windows server 2008 R2 64 bit
- .Net Framework 4.5.2

Comment: Is your local dev machine 32-bit or 64-bit?  Is that different than the deployment server?  Is your configuration "Any CPU"?

Comment: @mellamokb: My dev machine and server are both 64 bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've reproduced `OutOfMemoryException` in unit test by changing `byte[] bytes = new byte[80000000];` to `byte[] bytes = new byte[52000000];` and running in loop (2 times). Test runner is 32 bit.

So back to IIS Express - I think you're using 32 bit version. You can change this at

> Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | Web Projects | Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanx, never knew IIS ran on 32 bit by default, always thought it followed the built configuration.

Comment: BTW - what's wrong with 80MB ? it's not even close to 2GB limit

Comment: @Royi, it turns out that when such an object is serialized/deserialized, memory consumption is much over than 80MB

Comment: @Royi, yeah, it still reproducible with Json.net 10. It must be also somehow related to test runner/visual studio. But regardless of unit test, it can also be reproduced with console app(32bit) with array of 220MB

Comment: 3 and a half years later, you saved me with this answer. Thanks.